# No docker-compose.yml when installing Laravel project

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose, composer-php, laravel-sail

env: macOS 12.6.3
Docker, Composer, PHP installed

Hello, I’m wondering if you have to manually install sail using

```
php artisan sail:install
```

every time I create projects.

Although I have installed laravel projects several times successfully, now it says “no configuration file provided: not found” when sail up when installing a new project and sail up. And there’s no docker-compose.yml file.

The question is that I need to manually install sail every time I make Laravel projects despite the fact that it did automatically installed sail before.

Thank you.

I have tried

```
php artisan sail:install
```

Comment: If docker you should use the port which you expose outside(Nginx or Apache), if port is 8090 you can use `localhost:8090`. No need to run `sail` or `artisan serve`

Comment: Please share more details. How is this problem related to Composer?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue on my Windows machine. You can install sail and get the *'docker-compose.yml'* file by following the steps from **Laravel Sail docs**:

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/sail

In the root of your application, run the following commands:

1. `composer require laravel/sail --dev`
2. `php artisan sail:install`

Comment: How do you run php if php is in the sail containers, and isn't available until sail is installed? It seems sail needs to be installed in order to run the sail commands to install sail. How does that work? All doc I can find assumes PHP is already up and running locally, when the idea of sail is surely that it uses containers that *don't* need PHP to be installed locally.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that this worked out of the box in previous versions of Laravel, however I am not able to get the docker-compose.yml automatically for Laravel 10.

If you are in an environment where you do not have composer installed and only intend to use Sail you could do the following:

1. Download the framework
   `curl -s "https://laravel.build/example-app" | bash`
2. Install all of the dependencies
   `docker run --rm \ -u "$(id -u):$(id -g)" \ -v "$(pwd):/var/www/html" \ -w /var/www/html \ laravelsail/php82-composer:latest \ composer install --ignore-platform-reqs`
3. create a `docker-compose.yml` file in the root directory

```html
# For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/sail
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.2
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.2/app
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
            - '${VITE_PORT:-5173}:${VITE_PORT:-5173}'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
            IGNITION_LOCAL_SITES_PATH: '${PWD}'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
```

4. Create shell alias `alias sail='[ -f sail ] && sh sail || sh vendor/bin/sail'`
5. Start sail `sail up -d`
6. Run `sail artisan sail:install` and select atleast mysql
7. Run `sail down` and then `sail up -d`